# Hide bucket items based on role

Tags: security, sitecore, buckets

Imagine I have the following content tree

- sitecore

  - content

    - home

      - KB articles (bucket)

        - article 1 (Template 1)
        - article 2 (Template 1)
        - article 3 (Template 2)

And the following roles -

- Role 1
- Role 2

I have the following scenarios.

1. Role 1 should have read/write access to Article 1 and Article 2, which are based on Template 1.
2. Role 2 should have read/write access to Article 3, which is based on Template 2.

Is there a way of achieving the above scenario in Sitecore?

Thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure but I think this might be better off on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the access rights on the `Standard Values` items of `Template 1` and `Template 2`.

Just set `read/write` or whatever you need on `Standard Values` of `Template 1` for the `Role 1` only. And set `read/write` or whatever you need on `Standard Values` of `Template 2` for the `Role 2` only.

After you do this, all the items which use `Template 1` and `Template 2` will inherit the access rights from the corresponding `Standard Values`.